# How to convert Ireland time to Indian time?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I want to change a date and time value received in Ireland format to the format used in India.

I tried this:

`14/09/2016 13:51:38-time(5,30,0)`

but I get a `#value` error.

Comment: I would suggest you to : **1.** Add some example of `input > output` expected **2.** Add your actual code.

Comment: Remove some duplicate text and rearranged syntax in order to resolve an ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your Irish time `(14/09/2016 13:51:38)` is in `A1`
then your Indian time: `$A$1+((5+30/60)/24)`
with of course the time difference being 5 hours 30 minutes in this example

Comment: Thank you for the formula, I have appplied in my sheet and it is working but for some cells it's still showing #Value error. Is there a way that I can send an excel sheet. and after applying this formula I am getting only time, no date.. I want both Date and time

Comment: You can use dropbox or whatever.
Yes you can display full date by going to cell properties and define the date format you want. E.g.: `aaaa/mm/jj hh:mm`

Answer (score 0):

As you were looking for a VBA solution, I would use DateAdd here: `DateAdd("n", -330, "14/09/2016 13:51:38")` in my example below I defined date ranges as I prefer to work that way, you could easily mould this into a loop.

```
Private Sub test()

Dim irTime, inTime As Date

irTime = Sheets(5).Cells(1, 1).Value
inTime = DateAdd("n", -330, irTime)

Sheets(5).Cells(1, 3).Value = inTime

End Sub
```

If you are still getting `#Value` errors I would look at the formatting of your Irish times and make sure taht they are all consitant and correctly formatted (don't forget to back-up incase you lose data playing around with formats).

[This](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=315:excel-vba-dates-a-time-format-function-user-defined-date-number-a-string-formats&catid=79&Itemid=475) is my go-to bookmark for DateAdd as I always forget the `"n"` interval for minutes, you might find it useful.